# No need to use escape seq. for ' in C#?

Tags: c#, escaping

On MSDN I can read that `\'` is escape sequence for `'` char. However I am able to use it in string without escape sequence like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press 'X' ");
```

How it is possible?

Comment: Huh, try explaining a bit more.

Answer (score 7):

But how would you write it as a `char`?

```
char c = '\'';
```

Answer (score 5):

[`char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (a single character literal) is a different data type than [`string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) (a multi character literal).

In C# a `char` is declared as:

```
var c = 'c';
```

whereas a `string` is declared as:

```
var s = "asdf";
```

As you can see the single quote (`'`)  would need to be escaped to declare a `char` containing the single quote:

```
var c = '\'';
```

Comment: Also would need to escape " characater~ var c = "this is a quote: \"";

Answer (score 3):

`\'` screening is needed for char literals. Reason is that `'` can be interpreted as literal boundary character. For strings it is meaningless because there is nothing to confuse with. In `strings` in turn `\"` makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It says that you have to escape ' for a char data type.

```
char c = ''';  // compiler throws error
char c = '\''; // valid
```